# make an existing game virtual reality game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 360-virtual-reality

I'm interested in taking an existing flying game and turn it into a virtual reality game. What would be required? I would like to be able to make the game respond to touch primarily and vision. Thank you!

Comment: checkout the documentation of Google VR SDK. it's very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Unity project for the existing flying game? Depending on how complex that game is, it could be relatively simple to use the free [SteamVR plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32647) to add VR support to the game.

If you don't have the Unity project for the existing game, then you've got to do everything from scratch. This includes game programming as well as acquiring/inserting assets, *inter alia*, which would be quite a lot of work.